# How can I iterate over Document objects using Java and avoid the error "can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"?

Tags: java, mongodb

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         Document document = Document.parse(String.format("{\"a\": %s}",line)); for(Document doc : document.get("a")) {
               docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>(doc));
           }
```

I am getting the error in the for loop `for (Document doc : document.get("a"))` that states,

> can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

How can I loop through the document(s) and avoid this error?

Answer (score -1):

What if you simply change the for loop to say

```
for (Document doc : document.get("a").toArray()) {

}
```